# Solving a "reversed" Stein equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $P$ and $Q$ be positive definite matrices. Consider the following matrix equation
$$\label{star}\tag{$\star$}
XPX^\top - P = -Q, \quad X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}.
$$

> **My question.** Is it true that any solution of \eqref{star} can be written as $X=(P-Q)^{1/2}TP^{-1/2}$ with $T$ being an arbitrary orthogonal matrix?

Comment: As (1.) an  straightforward  computation shows that if  $X$  is  a  solution then $A={(P-Q)}^{-1/2}XP^{1/2}$ satisfies $AA^T=Id$.However we need  to add  the  assumption $Q<P$

Comment: Have you tested (2) on at least, say, 10000 examples before asking here?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I did run some numerical simulations in matlab. However, after posting this question, I found out that there was a bug in the generation of a random orthogonal matrix. Once fixed this, counterexamples can be found. I will now edit the OP.

Comment: @AliTaghavi It would be useful if you posted your comment as an answer, so that this question can be marked as answered/accepted. You don't need much more detail.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  Thanks for  your  suggestion.  I  wrote  an  answer to the  previous  version of  the  question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  am  considering the  previous  version of  your  question which contained two parts.

Part 1)  We assume $Q<P$ which  means that $P-Q$ is  a strictly positive  matrix. Of course this condition is a necessary condition for the equation to have a solution. So we assume $P, Q,P-Q$ are positive invertible matrices.

First  note that the equation has always a solution. Here is a proof:

WLOG we may assume that the positive matrix  $P-Q$ is a diagonal matrix. Because every positive matrix is orthonormally  diagonalizable. We consider the inner product whose tensor matrix is $P$. Now a solution to your matrix equation corresponds to a basis consistong of mutually orthogonal vectors whose norms are not necessarilly unit but are determined by the entries of the diagonal matrix $P-Q$.
Now one  can show  that if $X$ is  a  solution of the  equation in your  question then $A={(P-Q)}^{-1/2}XP^{1/2}$ satisfies $AA^T=Id$

Part 2) The  answer is yes if  we further assume that  $PQ=QP$.

Note that the  spectrum of the  solution  $X={(P-Q)}^{1/2}T P^{-1/2}$ is  equal  to the  spectrum  of  $T{(P-Q)}^{1/2}P^{-1/2}$  because  $AB$  and  $BA$ have  the  same  spectrum.  Now the  commutativity assumption $PQ=QP$ implies that $H={(P-Q)}^{1/2}P^{-1/2}$ is  a  positive  matrix.

Now we use the  following  lemma:

**Lemma:** If $T$ is  an orthonormal  matrix and $H$  is  a positive  matrix Then $\lambda_{min} (TH)= \lambda_{min}(H)$  and  $\lambda_{Max} (TH)=\lambda_{Max}(H)$.

**Proof:** It is  sufficient to prove the  following  statement. Then the  lemma  is  a consequence of  a  simple  rescaling and  consideration of the fact  that "The spectrum of the inverse is equal to the  inverse of the  spectrum"

**Statement:** If  all  eigenvaluse of  a  positive  matrix  $H$ lie in the  interior of  the  unit  disc of the complex plane then the  same is true  for  all  eigenvalues of  $TH$ where $T$ is  an arbitrary  orthonormal  matrix:

**Proof  of  the  Statement:**  WLOG we may  assume  that  $H$ is  a  diagonal  matrix because  every  positive  matrix  is  unitary equivalent to  a  diagonal matrix. For  diagonal  matrices the  statement is  obvious. Because if $THV=\lambda V$  for  some  $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$  with $|\lambda|>1$  and  $V \in \mathbb{C}^n$ then $|HV|>|V|$  which is  impossible since  all  entries of  diagonal  matrix  $H$  are positive  element less than $1$.

The  second  part of the previous version of  your question is  a  motivation to  consider the following    question in the context of  complex $C^*$ algebras. We keep  the same notations $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{Max}$ for the case of  $C^*$ algebras.

**Question :** let  $A$  be  a simple $C^*$ algebra and $u$ be  a  unitary element with the  property that for  every two positive element $a,b$ we have

$$\lambda_{min} (aub)=\lambda_{min}(ab)\\ \lambda_{Max}(aub)=\lambda_{Max}(ab)$$

Does this  imply that $u$ is  an scalar element?

Comment: I can't follow this "the  spectrum of the solution $X={(P-Q)}^{1/2}T P^{-1/2}$ is  equal  to the  spectrum  of  $T{(P-Q)}^{1/2}P^{-1/2}$  because  $AB$  and  $BA$ have  the same spectrum". The later statement  implies just that the spectrum of the product of some matrices is invariant under cyclic permutation, not every permutation. am I missing something?

Comment: @Mahdi  Thanks for your comment. Yes you are completely right.  the spectrum is invariant under cyclic permutation. But our extra assumption $PQ=QP$  implies that the permutation I used is actualy a cyclic permutation. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Could you recommend any resources on inverse solutions to the Stein equation?

Comment: @SpencerKraisler  My  apology for my late repley. To be honest the  answer I provided in the post was based on  immediate computation. It was not based on a reference on Stein equation. at the time of  answering I was not aware of the special terminology, i.e stein equation, for  such equation. So I do not know any resource on the topic. I will come back you if I find some resources